# How to get input from searchview to textview

Tags: android, searchview

Is there another way to get the input of searchview and put it into textview? It seems that the getText() and setText() method are not applicable to searchview.

Or

Is there a way to transfer the input from EditText to Searchview?

Please help me to look for necessary resources/codes/method about the above question. Thank you. Here is my code:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showResults(newText);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    tvInput = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvInput);
    showResults(query);
//  searchView.getQuery().toString();
    tvInput.setText(searchView.getQuery().toString());
    return false;
}
```

I also do it in other way. Here:

```
tvInput = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvInput);
                tvInput.setText(searchView.getQuery());
```

Comment: are you adding the searchview on show of options menu?

Comment: if you need to set it inside onQueryTextSubmit, you can directly use the query parameter that is passed in.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

for searchView to editText

```
editText.setText(searchView.getQuery());
```

for editText to SearchView

```
searchView.setQuery(editText.getText(),false);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#getQuery()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setQuery(java.lang.CharSequence,boolean)

Comment: Hi Im trying your searchview to textview instead of editText. But It still doesnt get input from searchview.

Comment: can you edit your question and post some code, also, is it returning null always or sometimes?

Comment: what does the showResults method do, can you try getting the query value before calling showResults()

Comment: Actually, it's working for invalid input only and not working for the words that are inside the database.

Comment: Yeah, its working even in after and before showResults() for invalid input only. What do you think is the problem. But still.. Thank you.. :))