# How to get a text from SearchView?

Tags: android

I need to get a text from `SearchView` and compare it to strings in my activity's `ListView` and show a `Toast` if the word in a `SearchView` is in my `ListView`. How do I do that? Here's my working code for the SearchView:

```
MenuItem ourSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
    
SearchView sv = (SearchView) ourSearchItem.getActionView();
    
sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get input from searchview to textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712247/how-to-get-input-from-searchview-to-textview)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To get text of `SearchView`, use `searchView.getQuery()`.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about this: if (Arrays.asList(arraylist).contains(sv.getQuery()) {//perform some action} but it doesn't work(

Comment: I can't say why this because I didn't see your code,but you can debug this,print value of `arraylist` and `Arrays.asList(arraylist)` and `sv.getQuery()`,notice that make sure your query string doesn't have space character,if so,use `trim()` to delete it.

Comment: This works but I had to use `searchView.query.toString()`

Answer (score 7):

try this code :

```
    MenuItem ourSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);

    SearchView sv = (SearchView) ourSearchItem.getActionView();

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```